# How best to handle a portrait mode and landscape mode in a single view?

Tags: ios4, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

My current understanding is that I have to assign the coordinates in the code itself instead of using the interface-builder. Is there a better way to do this?

Currently I am trying to handle a login view. It works well in portrait mode but in landscape mode few of the contents are hidden.  Please suggest how to handle this.

Thanks

GuruPrasad R Gujjar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this one of two ways. The first is what you suggested and change all of their frames, and second is to just have a separate view that is in landscape mode and switch it out on rotation.

For both cases you need to implement these two methods

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        //put the portrait orientation here
        self.usernameField.frame=CGRectMake(xPortraitLocation, yPortraitLocation, xWidth, yWidth);
        ...

    }
    else{
        //do the same thing with everything but for landscape mode
    }
```

With a seperate view you just switch them out by saying self.view=self.lanscapeView or self.portraitView.

If I am going to use the first method I sometimes like to create a fake view in the interface builder so that I can put all my items in the correct locations and look under the location tab which eliminates the guess and check of assigning the numbers.

Hope this helps.